# SUMIFS on a range of data

Tags: excel, sumifs

I currently have this formula in Excel:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS('OPPORTUNITY LIST Current Month'!$W:$W,'OPPORTUNITY LIST Current Month'!$J:$J,"Open",'OPPORTUNITY LIST Current Month'!$A:$A,'Opportunity Allocation'!$A:$A))
```

`'Opportunity allocation'` is a sheet with the unique identifier allocated by name in a column, so for this person column A of `'Opportunity allocation'` has all the unique identifiers of their lines of data in the `'OPPORTUNITY LIST current month'` sheet.

This formula works and returns sum of column `W` for all of the rows matching identifiers allocated to the person.

The problem is it basically crashes Excel when I run it, taking 20+ minutes to run just on one cell which is obviously making it a nightmare as I need to do this for ten different values across a team of thirty people!

Can anyone help me write this in a more efficient way?
I assume `SUMPRODUCT` is what's causing my problems?

Comment: Please add some sample code you've been working on.

Comment: The problem is your final criterion. You are asking Excel to consider more than a million cells - 'Opportunity Allocation'!$A:$A - for that criterion! Which effectively means that Excel has to perform the equivalent of more than a million separate SUMIF constructions and then sum all those results. Do you really have more than a million different criteria which you would like to be considered for the range 'OPPORTUNITY LIST Current Month'!$A:$A?

Comment: Aha! Thank you, thats so obvious. It didn't even occur to me. I've cut it down to a sensible number of cells and its running instantly!

Comment: Ok. You're welcome. If it's ok with you I'll paste my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your final criterion. You are asking Excel to consider more than a million cells - 'Opportunity Allocation'!$A:$A - for that criterion!

Which effectively means that Excel has to perform the equivalent of more than a million separate SUMIF constructions and then sum all those results. Do you really have more than a million different criteria which you would like to be considered for the range 'OPPORTUNITY LIST Current Month'!$A:$A?

Regards